# Iterating over the dimensions of a boost::multi_array

Tags: c++, templates, boost, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

I'm trying to write some dimension-independent code for a template class in c++, using a boost::multi_array (though if other containers/data structures are better at this, I'd be happy to hear about it).

Given a dimension, I would like to iterate over the full range of every other dimension, returning a 1d view along the selected dimension.  This is fairly straightforward, or at least it appears to be from the boost documentation.

What I can't figure out how to do is iterate the selected dimension over all of the dimensions of the array, when the dimension of the array is known at compile time.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: How generic do you want the code to be? Sounds like something that could be solved with variadic templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can do it with boost::multi_array, heres some sample code to create a 2D view of a 3D multi_array:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;

    array_type myArray3D(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

    // Assign values to the elements
    int values = 0;
    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    {
            for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            {
                    for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                    {
                            myArray3D[i][j][k] = values++;
                    }
            }
    }
    // Verify values
    int verify = 0;
    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    {
            for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            {
                    for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                    {
                            std::cout << "[" << i << "]";
                            std::cout << "[" << j << "]";
                            std::cout << "[" << k << "] = ";
                            std::cout << myArray3D[i][j][k] << std::endl;
                            assert(myArray3D[i][j][k] == verify++);
                    }
            }
    }

    typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;
    array_type::index_gen indices;

    // Create a new view with 2 dimentions fixing the 2nd dimention to 1
    array_type::array_view<2>::type myView =
    myArray3D[indices[range()][1][range()]];
    std::size_t numDims = myView.size();
    std::cout << "numDims = " << numDims << std::endl;

    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    {
            for (index j = 0; j != 2; ++j)
            {
                    std::cout << "[" << i << "]";
                    std::cout << "[" << j << "] = ";
                    std::cout << myView[i][j] << std::endl;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know how to create subviews for a given set of dimensions, the question was about how to iterate which dimension(s) are being viewed over all the dimensions of the array.

Comment: Specifically, I want to call a function on the set of all 1D slices along a dimension x, then the same function on the set of all slices along dimension y, then z, w, etc.

Comment: But I need to iterate over which dimension I'm iterating over.  The problem I'm facing is: given `n` dimensions, iterate over the dimensions themselves, not the points in each dimension.

Comment: Basically, I need to do something along the lines of `indices[range()][i][j]`, then `indices[i][range()][j]` then `indices[i][j][range()]`, but for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: @Dan - Normally you can construct the indeces variable and you can also ask the array its dim size... I'm not familiar with advanced use of multi array but I'll give it a try in my next spare time... ;-)